# What are RPackageTags? How are they related to Monticello Packages?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I try to learn about `RPackageTag`s:

1. It seems `RPackageTag`s are just something like *sub-packages*?
2. Unlike let’s say tags in OS X, one item (here one class) cannot have more than one tag?
3. A tag is always specific to an `RPackage`? The tags in *Package1-Tag1* and *Package2-Tag1* are not the same, i.e. are two different instances of `RPackageTag`?
4. There is the possibilty that *Package1-Tag1* is just an `RPackage` and also the possibility that *Package1-Tag1* is the combination of `RPackage` *Package1* and `RPackageTag` *Tag1*?

Is that right? What is the idea behind the introduction of `RPackageTag`s?

How are `RPackageTag`s related to Monticello packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers:

1. Yes, they are like subpackages
2. For now, yes. This is because we needed to keep some compatibility between RPackages and System Categories and we decided (for now), that the scheme would be: RPackage+Tag = SystemCategory. This will change in the future, by removing system categories and allowing tags to be like OSX tags.
3. For now, yes... see point (2) :)
4. No, you cannot. This is because of organisation issues derived also from the attach RPackage+Tag to a SystemCategory: If you have a package A-B and a Package A with tag B, both would share the SystemCategory A-B... which is seriously bad for the organization of the system.

Of course, as you can see, the real problem here is to have an ancient way of organisation still in system. This will change, in Pharo4 or (most probably) in Pharo5, and for now we need to live with this convenience solution.

Comment: 4. I did not mean at the same time of course. But there seem to be a lot of packages in the system that have names like _Bar-Foo_ and are only a package and not a package with a tag?

Comment: You have "promote" and "demote" menu options to move from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

Ring package structure was adopted in Pharo 3. Approximately what was known to be an MC package became RPachage, pure-smalltalk categories disappeared and were replaced by `RPackageTag`s. You can think about it as a way to create categorise classes inside your MC package. I don't know what Pharo board will decide in future, but for now you can have only 1 tag per class.

Comment: RPackage and Ring are two different frameworks, orthogonal between them. While RPackage purpose (the "R" means "Real", not "Ring") is to organise classes in the system, Ring purpose is to offer a common abstraction between "live" objects and "dead" objects (objects in the system and objects in the history).